# Flutter - audio player error: Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: then " <asynchronous suspension> "

Tags: android, flutter, dart, assets

I'm trying to make some buttons that produce a sound when clicked, I did remove the package and installing another one, tried flutter clean, restarted the studio loads of times, but nothing seemed to happen and it keeps giving me that error: **[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: assets/audiofolder/assets_note4.wav
E/flutter ( 8639): #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:227:7)
E/flutter ( 8639): 
E/flutter ( 8639): #1      AudioCache._fetchAsset (package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart:75:12)
E/flutter ( 8639): 
E/flutter ( 8639): #2      AudioCache.fetchToMemory (package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart:82:24)
E/flutter ( 8639): 
E/flutter ( 8639): #3      AudioCache.load (package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart:97:31)
E/flutter ( 8639): 
E/flutter ( 8639): #4      AudioCache.getAbsoluteUrl (package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart:192:17)
E/flutter ( 8639): 
E/flutter ( 8639): #5      AudioCache.play (package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart:122:18)
E/flutter ( 8639): 
E/flutter ( 8639):** Whenever I click a button

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
    ));

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  void playLocalAsset(int x) {
    final player = AudioCache();
    player.play('audiofolder/assets_note$x.wav'); // error that i can't solve
  }

  Expanded buttonKey({Color color, int number}) {
    return Expanded(
      child: FlatButton(
        color: color,
        onPressed: () {
          playLocalAsset(number);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            buttonKey(color: Colors.red, number: 1),
            buttonKey(color: Colors.yellow, number: 2),
            buttonKey(color: Colors.orange, number: 3),
            buttonKey(color: Colors.green, number: 4),
            buttonKey(color: Colors.teal, number: 5),
            buttonKey(color: Colors.blue, number: 6),
            buttonKey(color: Colors.purple, number: 7),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
description: A new Flutter application.

publish_to: 'none' 
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  audioplayers: ^0.18.3


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - audiofolder/
```

Answer (score 1):

If `audiofolder` not inside `assets or another folder` you can just type `filename`.

**For Example this my code**

```
 return AudioCache().play('audios/zapsplat_multimedia_game_sound_basic_digital_retro_incorrect_error_negative_005_40466.mp3');
```

This is `pubspec.yaml`

```
assets:
- assets/
```

In my case, the audio file inside in `assets/audios` so you must type without `assets/` because the assets have initialize in `pubspec.yaml`

Hopefully can help you

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me, but after I click the button for few times, I get this error and it stops producing sound: 
E/MediaPlayerNative(14047): error (1, -2147483646)
E/MediaPlayer(14047): Error (1,-2147483646)
E/MediaPlayerNative(14047): pause called in state 0, mPlayer(0xc347ff00)
E/MediaPlayerNative(14047): error (-38, 0)
E/MediaPlayerNative(14047): Attempt to perform seekTo in wrong state: mPlayer=0xc347ff00, mCurrentState=0
E/MediaPlayerNative(14047): error (-38, 0)
E/MediaPlayer(14047): Error (1,-2147483646)

Comment: what I see from your code, is your goals to create sfx?

Comment: Kind of, my goal is to make a sort of instrument that has multiple buttons to play different sounds

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://youtu.be/NnAF0LeAVoc

Comment: I tried to change some of the code based on the video, but unfortunately, that didn't help, I'm guessing it's the package itself that holds the problem